# How does the include works even thought it's in an else statement?PHP

Tags: php

I'm including the form in the else statement it appears in the
   browser how/why does it appear even though it's in the else statement
   should it check first the if else state men then appear??can anybody
   explain me why does this happening this is the code

### this is the index.php page

```
    <?php
    require 'core.php';
    require 'connect.php';

    if(loggedin()){
        echo 'you\'re logged in .<a href="logout.php">Logout</a> ';
    }else{
        include 'loginform.php';
    }
    ?>
```

### this is the loginform.php

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password_hash = md5($password);
        if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
            $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password_hash'";

            if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
                $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
                if($query_num_rows == 0){
                    echo 'invalid user name / password';
                }else if($query_num_rows == 1){
                    $user_id = mysql_result($query_run, 0 ,'id');
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo 'you must supply usrename and password';
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST">
        <label>username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <label>password:</label><input type ="passwrod" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
```

Comment: where is the code in function loggedin() ?

Comment: your getting false value in your loggedin function,that's the reason.

Comment: @CamiloGo this is the function   function loggedin(){
             if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
                 return true;
             } else {
             return false;    
             }
        }

Comment: @Roljhon no the function does work I'm asking why does the form appear when i run the code even thought it's the first time

Comment: of course, it will show at the first time, your session user_id is not yet set on that moment, so your condition inside your loggedin function will return false. But not sure really what you're getting in your end and from what scenario that you're really getting the issue. I'm only speaking from what you said.

Comment: oh yeah thank you I think that this is the problem thank you so much @Roljhon

Comment: tell me you're not using this in a live environment right now or plan on to. @OmarAbdelaziz

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm sorry what do u mean? :)